# check result for importing controller

Tags: cakephp, controller

what if I imported controller and want to check that

```
    App::import('Controller', 'Users');
```

is successful or not. How can I check it got imported or not. If that controller is not there, how can I detect that?

Comment: Why are you trying to import a Controller? This is not something you should really be doing in Cake. If you need to share common code between controllers use a Component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple:

```
if (class_exists('UsersController')) { /*...*/ };
```

But you should use `App::uses()` instead.

However, I'm pretty sure you're about to violate the MVC pattern:

**If you "need" something from the controller somewhere else your application architecture is screwed up!**

Refactor and put your code in the proper place. If you need to share common code between controllers use a Component. If it is business logic put it in a model.